# How Can I Add to Django's Default Logging?

Tags: django, logging

I'm using Django 1.6 and would like to add to—not replace—[Django's default logging](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.6/django/utils/log.py#L31-L75). Specifically, I want to make it so that *in addition to Django's default logging behavior*, any log record with a log level of `DEBUG` or higher gets written to a log file that gets automatically rotated.

Based on what I've found through searches and my own experimenting, it seems like you have to redefine all of the logging (Django's defaults plus my rotating file logging), even when using `'disable_existing_loggers': False`. I figure I'm probably doing something wrong.

I'd like to see an example of what to put in my settings.py file that will allow me to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

`settings.py` is just Python, so we can do:

```
from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING

# Use defaults as the basis for our logging setup
LOGGING = DEFAULT_LOGGING

# We need some formatters. These ones are from the docs.
LOGGING['formatters'] = {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
}

# A log file handler that rotates periodically
LOGGING['handlers'].update({
    'rotate': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
        'filename': '/tmp/debug.log',
    }
})

# The default 'django' logger is a catch-all that does nothing. We replace it with
# a rotating file handler.
LOGGING['loggers'].update({
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['rotate'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    }
})

# If you don't want to completely replace the django handler, you could do something
# like this instead:
#LOGGING['loggers']['django']['handlers'] += ['rotate']
```

This will add your rotating file handler to the existing handlers, define the basic formatters, and replace the catch-all logger (which does nothing) with one that  replace the default logger

Comment: Thanks, but is this really the best way, and the way intended by the Django developers? [This part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) of the logging documentation says: "Prior to Django 1.5, the `LOGGING` setting always overwrote the [default Django logging configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/logging/#default-logging-configuration). From Django 1.5 forward, it is possible to get the project’s logging configuration merged with Django’s defaults, hence you can decide if you want to add to, or replace the existing configuration."

Comment: So it does. What are you doing now?

Comment: I'm just using Django's defaults.

Comment: You said, "Based on what I've found through searches and my own experimenting, it seems like you have to redefine all of the logging (Django's defaults plus my rotating file logging)". What have you tried to do when adding a logger of your own?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I tried this. It seems to do what you're asking.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'rotate': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/debug.log',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['rotate'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: I put this in my settings.py, set `DEBUG` to `False`, and then accessed a view that executes `self.this_does_not_exist()`. This caused a 500 error to occur. It got logged to the file, as expected, but I did not receive an email about it. I then commented out the code from your answer and accessed that same view. This time, I did receive an email about the error, but it, of course, didn't get logged. How can I have both?

Comment: I tested and got the same behaviour you describe. It seems what you're asking for isn't possible :( there is an option 'incremental' that allows patching of the config dictionary, however it's very limited in scope - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#incremental-configuration - you may have to simply copy-paste the default config dictionary and augment it with a rotating file handler